# return array value from arrays where key value exisits

Tags: php, arrays

Given this *static method* on a `DummyClass`, please tell me how I could ask the returned data to give me the **order position** *of the array in the main array*.

```
public static function editableColumns()
{
    return array(
        array('attribute' => 'name',
              'heading'   => 'Name',
              'type'      => 'singleline',
              'width'     => '50%'
        ),
        array('attribute' => 'displayName',
              'heading'   => 'Display Name',
              'type'      => 'singleline',
              'width'     => '50%'
        ),
    );
}
```

For example if I want `attribute == 'name'`, *return 0* (because the name attribute is in the first array. If I wanted `attribute == 'displayName'` it should *return 1*.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Try to write some code. Use `foreach`, `break`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function editableColumns()
{
    return array(
        array('attribute' => 'name',
              'heading'   => 'Name',
              'type'      => 'singleline',
              'width'     => '50%'
        ),
        array('attribute' => 'displayName',
              'heading'   => 'Display Name',
              'type'      => 'singleline',
              'width'     => '50%'
        ),
    );
}

$key = 'attribute';
$needle = 'displayName';

$result = key(
    array_filter(
        editableColumns(),
        function($entry) use($key, $needle) {
            return $entry[$key] == $needle;
        }
    )
);

var_dump($result);
```

Note that if the key/value pair exists in more than one entry, then only the first will be returned in $result

Answer (score 1):

Use a `foreach` loop:

```
public static function getKey($array, $searchKey, $searchValue, $multipleKeys = false){
    $keys = [];
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if(!isset($value[$searchKey]) || $value[$searchKey] != $searchValue)
            continue;

        if(!$multipleKeys)
            return $key;

        $keys[] = $key;
    }

    if(!$multipleKeys)
        return false;

    return empty($keys) ? false : $keys;
}
```

You can call this method like this:

```
$key = Class::getKey(Class::editableColumns(), 'attribute', 'name'); //0
$keys = Class::getKey(Class::editableColumns(), 'type', 'singleline', true); //[0, 1]
```